# PHP on IIS6, Windows Server 2003. Enabling cURL causes CGI Error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, php, iis, curl

I'm running an IIS6 server on Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2.

I've installed PHP on the server, and MOST of it is working fine. However, if I try to enable the cURL extension for PHP, I get the following error when I try to run ANY php script:

```
CGI Error

The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers.
```

As soon as I disable the cURL extension, every script works just fine.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this fixed it for me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756569/installing-php-curl-on-iis